# Does Microsoft SQL Server 2014 has parameter relate maximum incoming request/sec?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-tuning

I'm not sure Microsoft SQL Server 2014 limit or unlimited incoming request(record or transaction)/sec.If it has parameter to config please share me please.

Comment: There is no limit on the number of requests. The server will process as much as it can. If you're looking at limiting resources, look at Resource Governor.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @DanGuzman My teammate use replication tool (dbmoto) to replicate data from as400 to MSSQL2014 but really slow replication,So they ask me MSSQL2014 have something limit or not because CPU and Disk usage is not peak.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks

Comment: If all looks good on the SQL box, I would look at the iSeries machine or tool.